# How to find functional square root of $\sin(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-analysis

Maybe I am overlooking something, but is there some easy way to find a function $x\to f(x)$ so that

$$(f\circ f)(x) = f(f(x)) = \sin(x)$$

on some interval, say $x\in [-\pi,\pi]\subset \mathbb R$ of real line? (Analytically or otherwise).

Comment: Yes, to satisfy the equation on $[-\pi,\pi]$ there is a very easy way... $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+4\pi & \text{if $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$,} \\ \sin(x) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Rahul : I don't want easiest, I want interesting or useful approach or preferably both.

Comment: There's no reason to expect such an $f$ should have a closed form, but one can write such an $f$ explicitly (albeit in nonclosed form) in terms of the iterates $\sin^{(k)}$ of $\sin$: https://mathoverflow.net/a/44727/26266 . It's perhaps worth mentioning that considering $x \mapsto \sin x$ gives a relatively well-behaved answer. It's not too hard to see, for example, that there is no continuous function $g$ for which $(g \circ g)(x) = -x$.

Comment: From your comments, it looks like you are looking for something way more specific than your question suggests. You should clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: @tomasz You are right. But sometimes I don't know how to formulate what I am looking for before I have gotten some examples of what I am not looking for.

Comment: see my question and self-answer at  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sebapi's idea is fine, but he has miscalculations. The coefficients of $f$ can be computed recursively with elementary finite computations. We start with
$$\sin x=x-{1\over3!}x^3+{1\over5!}x^5-{1\over7!} x^7+{1\over9!}x^9+{1\over11!}x^{11}\ldots\tag{1}$$and make the Ansatz
$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k\ .$$
Putting the subsequent coefficients of $f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)-\sin x$ to zero we first have to solve $a_1^2=1$. I choose $a_1=1$ (and leave $a_1=-1$ to you). It then becomes quickly apparent that all $a_{2j}=0$, so that it seems reasonable to replace the above Ansatz by
$$f(x):=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{2j-1} x^{2j-1}\ .$$
I did the computations with Mathematica, and obtained
$$f(x)=x-{1\over12}x^3-{1\over160}x^5-{53\over40\,320}x^7-{23\over71\,680}x^9-{92\,713\over1\,277\,337\,600}x^{11}+\ \ldots\ .\tag{2}$$
Computing $f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$ up to the $x^{11}$ term using $(2)$ gives exactly $(1)$. The numerators appearing in $(2)$ are listed at OEIS under [A098932](http://oeis.org/A098932), where reference is made to the problem at hand.

Comment: Yes *finite* calculations, but it doesn't mean it will be particularly efficient.

Comment: see my question and self-answer at  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge

Comment: Here's something to improve the efficiency:  let's say f(x)=x-x³/12-x⁵/160-53x⁷/40320-23x⁹/71680-... (the function you described earlier).  Let's say rin(x) is the functional square root of sin(x) (that is to say rin(rin(x))=sin(x)).  rin(x) can be approximated by f(x).  An even better approximation, however would be asin(f(sin(x)).  Even better than that, asin(asin(f(sin(sin(x))))).  Better still, asin(asin(asin(asin(f(sin(sin(sin(sin(x))))))))).  Every time you replace x with sin(x) and arcsine the result, your approximation becomes better.  But there must be just as many sines as arcsines.

Comment: DISCLAIMER TO MY PREVIOUS COMMENT: I did not come up with this solution by myself.  I got it from a paper a few years ago, but I can't find the paper today, unfortunately.  I should note that the paper mentioned this method works also on functional cube roots, fourth roots, etc. (provided you can come up with a decent approximation for f(x)).  From what I remember though, this isn't universal to all functions, in some cases this does diverge.

Answer (score 1):

We will be solving  Abel functional equation,
$$  \alpha( \sin z) = \alpha(z) + 1.$$

Given a specific $x$ with $x_1 = \sin x$ and $ x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ it is a result of Jean Ecalle at Orsay that we may take
$$ \alpha(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \; \frac{3}{x_n^2}  \; + \; \frac{6 \log x_n}{5}  \; + \; \frac{79  x_n^2}{1050}   \; + \; \frac{29  x_n^4}{2625}  \; - \; n.$$

In particular 
$$ f_{1/2} (x)  = \alpha^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \alpha(x)   \right) $$

Comment: This sounds very interesting. Can you perhaps give me some reference to Abels functional equation and this result?

Comment: @mathreadler  [I] Dynamics in One Complex Variable (third addition) by John Milnor [II] A History of Complex Dynamics by Daniel S. Alexander [III] Iterative Functional Equations by Kuczma, Choczewski, and Ger.

Answer (score 1):

In the paper *Finding a Compositional Square Root of Sine*, available (but presently paywalled) in [The American Mathematical Monthly, 129:9, 816-830](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2022.2105054), Tongtong Chen and Edward Scheinerman offer the example
$$
f(x) = \min (-\sin(x), -\arcsin(\sin(x)), \qquad x \in \mathbb{R},
$$
which satisfies $f(f(x)) = \sin(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here is a piece of the graph of $f$:
[image]

As suggested by the graph, this example $f$ is continuous, $2\pi$-periodic, and satisfies
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} -\sin(x), & -\pi \leq x \leq 0, \\ 
-x, & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, \\ x - \pi, & \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \pi, \end{cases}$$
a piecewise representation that is useful for verifying $f(f(x))=\sin(x)$ via case analysis.

The paper also discusses more general problems of finding compositional square roots.

Comment: This function is somewhat dishonest. It does satisfy $f(f(x))=\sin x$, but only by virtue of the fact that one application of $f$ accomplishes the *full* mapping $x\mapsto \sin x$ (up to sign), and the other application essentially leaves the argument unchanged, $x\mapsto x$. For a legitimate functional square root, I would expect each application to perform at least part of the mapping, as does the analytic function offered by the other answers.

Comment: OK, but it does offer a continuous example in what at least some people would regard as a "closed form," which I did not see given in previous answers.  (It is similar in spirit to an example given in a comment on the OP - which was also criticized, as not "interesting" or "useful" - but that example is not continuous.)  As I see it, such examples are useful precisely because they put pressure on notions (such as "accomplish[ing] the full mapping") that are not explicit in the OP.  The paper may also be of independent interest because it considers the problem in a more general setting.

Answer (score 0):

As $f \circ f$ has a series development near 0, we can try to find a function with a similar property. For instance for the function square root of $exp(-x)$:
$$
\exp(x) = x - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{6} x^3 + \ldots
$$
and identify the coefficient of the series of $f$:
$$
f(x) = x - \frac{1}{4} x^2 + \frac{1}{48} x^3 + \ldots
$$
Intuitively, this constructive method would identify $f$. But one would need to further check out the coefficients recursion to prove that the series converges, and therefrom get existence and uniqueness.

EDIT:
as pointed out by Deepak in comments below, used the expansion of $\exp(-x)$ instead of $\sin(x)$. Christian Blatter above used the proper expansion.

Comment: I agree that if they have potence series, then this makes sense. But I don't see how to calculate this in practice. $f(f(x))$ in terms of this potence series will be linear combinations of lots of self-convolutions of unknown coefficients. These self convolution will give second order polynomials in infinite variables to identify the constants 1,-1/2,1/6 etc.

Comment: Your series expansion for $\sin x$ appears to be wrong.

Comment: @Deepak : Yes it is, but that is not the main obstacle to overcome with the approach.

Comment: The correct method for this was published by Jean Ecalle, see my self answer at see my question and self-answer at  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge